# why doesn't work the `--includes` key of `git config` command for me?

Tags: git

I use Git-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.exe from [here](http://git-for-windows.github.io/).

I am learning Git and I am reading the documentation about `git config` command. I see this:

> `--[no-]includes`
>  Respect `include.*` directives in config files when looking up values. Defaults to on.

and this:

> INCLUDES
>   You can include one config file from another by setting the special
>   include.path variable to the name of the file to be included. The
>   included file is expanded immediately, as if its contents had been
>   found at the location of the include directive. If the value of the
>   include.path variable is a relative path, the path is considered to be
>   relative to the configuration file in which the include directive was
>   found. The value of include.path is subject to tilde expansion: ~/ is
>   expanded to the value of $HOME, and ~user/ to the specified user’s
>   home directory. See below for examples.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> # Core variables
> [core]
>         ; Don't trust file modes
>         filemode = false
> # Our diff algorithm
> [diff]
>         external = /usr/local/bin/diff-wrapper
>         renames = true
> [branch "devel"]
>         remote = origin
>         merge = refs/heads/devel
> # Proxy settings
> [core]
>         gitProxy="ssh" for "kernel.org"
>         gitProxy=default-proxy ; for the rest
> [include]
>         path = /path/to/foo.inc ; include by absolute path
>         path = foo ; expand "foo" relative to the current file
>         path = ~/foo ; expand "foo" in your $HOME directory
> ```

I created such `d:\server.gitconfig` file:

```
[http]
  proxy = http://@proxy2:8080
```

Also I added into `C:\Users\Andrey\.gitconfig` file (this is the same like `--global` key) such `include` group:

```
[include]
  path = /d/server.gitconfig
```

But when I launch a command

```
git config --list
```

or

```
git config --includes --list
```

I see the `include.path=/d/server.gitconfig` record instead of `http.proxy=http://@proxy2:8080`.
Also, when I launch a command

```
git config http.proxy
```

or

```
git config --includes http.proxy
```

I don't see my `http.proxy` settings. Why doesn't occuring the including?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git), this only works with Windonws-style path in the git config file:

```
[include]
  path = c:\\prgs\\server.gitconfig
```

Note the double `\\` as a path separator.

*Then*, the included config file is read and expended immediately.

This works with space in the path too:

```
git config --global include.path "c:\prgs\test with space\server.gitconfig"
```

(no need for `\\` on the `git config` command line)

That gives:

```
[include]
    path = c:\\prgs\\test with space\\server.gitconfig
```

(no double-quotes needed inside the `gitconfig` file itself)

Comment: Thank you, @VonC. How can I write a file which directory's name has the spaces? I tried this: `git config --global --add "D:\\123 456\\78 90\\server.gitconfig"` but it doesn't work. And this too: `git config --global --add \"D:\\123 456\\78 90\\server.gitconfig\"`

Comment: @Bush I have edited the answer to illustrates that it does work with a path including spaces in it.